# Obtener registros del dia anterior

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Que tal amigos necesito devolver los registros del dia anterior en CodeIgniter, cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Aca el codigo en mi modelo:

```
public function getOrdenes(){
    $this->db->where("fecha", date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->where("estado","1");
    $resultados = $this->db->get("pedidos");


    $return = array();

    foreach ($resultados->result() as $pedido)
    {
        $return[$pedido->id] = $pedido;
        $return[$pedido->id]->mesas = $this->getPedidosMesas($pedido->id); // Get the categories sub categories
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Busque con los amicos ingleses, y encontre una solución y si me funciono, dejo aca la respuesta:

```
public function getOrdenesPendientes(){
    $this->db->where("fecha", date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 days")));
    $this->db->where("estado","1");
    $resultados = $this->db->get("pedidos");


    $return = array();

    foreach ($resultados->result() as $pedido)
    {
        $return[$pedido->id] = $pedido;
        $return[$pedido->id]->mesas = $this->getPedidosMesas($pedido->id); // Get the categories sub categories
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Estaría bueno que si encontraste la respuesta en StackOverflow en Inglés, dejes la referencia :D

Answer (score 0):

Si usas SQL te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM ordenes_pendientes
WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```